# What is the advantage to build a Fortran GUI application upon Fortran libraries such as gino-graphics or wininteractor?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, fortran

**Summarization:**  Simply a matter of taste.

===================================================

It seems that famous Fortran GUI libraries include:

Gino-graphics (commercial, whole-set)
http://www.gino-graphics.com/

Winteracter (commercial, whole-set)
http://www.winteracter.com/

MatFor (commercial, whole-set)
http://www.ancad.com/index.php

DISLIN (free, chart)
http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/

However, Fotran is specialized in numerical programming. Because the Delphi language excels at GUI programming in Windows platform, Java (C++/Qt) is quite amazing in cross-platform GUI programming, what is the `noticeable advantage` to build a Fortran GUI front-end upon mature Fortran GUI libraries over inter-operating with other mature GUI libraries in Delphi or Java (C++/Qt)?

Comment: One possible advantage would be to stick to a codebase in a single language. That's one of the reasons why my numerical analysis app is written entirely in Delphi.

Comment: @David: Thank your for your comments! Then I am wondering whether you have tried the Fortran GUI libraries, or even tried to write your entire app in Fortran?

Comment: @Xichen No, the thought of writing anything in Fortran, let alone a GUI, makes me physically ill. If you keep asking, I'll have to go and have a lie down!!   ;-)

Comment: @David: Oh! :D I can see you are big fan of Delphi!

Comment: @Xichen Actually it's more the loathing of Fortran that's coming out here. It's good for some things, but not GUI work.

Comment: @David: You are right. I should think hard about what I need.

Comment: @Xichen Li - A bit offtopic, but maybe worth checking out: http://books.google.com/books?id=zkDEJFt_jlwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=building+compaq+visual+fortran+lawrence&source=bl&ots=HSOen0ASem&sig=ebpJODiuaWvQ99SuvmoPFYDxrds&hl=en&ei=T6h6Tf_DJJiesAaDsZGGDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully written delphi code that interacts with fortran libraries in the past.  It's relatively straightforward to build a windows dll wrapper for the fortran libraries and then call this from within your Delph gui.

Comment: When I link to Fortran, it's always been F77 and I use f2c followed by bcc32 followed by `{$LINK}`. It works really well with no deployment issues! f2c is one of the greatest programs in the world in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Keith: Thank you for sharing your experience! I am wondering whether you have tried Fortran-based GUI libraries, and if yes, what is your opinion about it?

Comment: @David: Thank you very much for sharing your experience! BTW, from the [webpage](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/changes), f2c has been actively maintained more than 20 years.

Comment: @Xichen If you already know Delphi, I'd run a mile from anything to do with Fortran. Either build the Fortran into a DLL as Keith says, or do it my way. How about you tell us more about what you are doing rather than letting us guess.

Comment: @David: Thanks for your suggestions! One of my teachers has an excellent F77 code base for scientific research. I myself tried to do some translation from F77 to F90, for fun and experience. However, I failed to go much further partly because I didn't learn make/CMake enough to maintain a project structure usable both for Linux development and for Windows development, nor did I learn FUnit enough to set up unit-testing to make myself confident about the translation. Thus, I thought about using Delphi to do unit-testing and so forth. Plus, Delphi offers good collections which are convenient.

Comment: @David: (Continued) Furthermore, the F77 codes return data which are easier to interpret when being visualized. I thus wonder whether I should go for fortran GUI or to mix languages. To translate the code base to use only Delphi is actually not interesting, at least not for my teacher. I really should think twice before making any further move.